# PHP Href Handling/Rewriting

Tags: php, url-rewriting, href

I have .htaccess settings that will rewrite anything to index.php to make static url. For example:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

`url: www.domain.com/home/article/news/`

I have no problems with this rewriting and i can handle the url using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. But, i have problem in my link. For example:

`<a href="home/article/recent">Recent News</a>`

When i click this link, the url will be `www.domain.com/home/article/news/home/article/recent` since the href value is not started with `"/"`.

Is there any way to rewrite my link in php or .htaccess? So when i forget to put `"/"` in href it's will not follow the current url? Thanks.

Comment: then put the `/` in your .htaccess `url:` just like what you did so even if your href doesnt have some `/` at front still it will work properly because your url ends with `/`

Answer (score 0):

**The .htaccess will not easily help you.** I'd say it is going to be error prone and hard to maintain as you add new paths. If you want to go that route you should do 301s so that your users do not see those odd paths. This will unfortunately add latency for the redirection.

**For PHP, it depends how you generate your output.** I'd say it is possible but you have to generate links rather than output it as straight HTML which will turn ugly IMO.

**It is certainly much less effort and will quickly become a habit to simply use absolute paths.**